# What is the most popular javascript framework in combination with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frameworks, widget

jquery is usually used as a low level js framework, the are still very many widget JS component frameworks.

What is the most popular additional library to jquery?

PS excluding jquery plugins and Jquery ui

Comment: Depends on what you want to do and there are a lot of jquery plugins.

Comment: Huh? jQuery is a low level framework?

Comment: @Marcel Korpel yes, it is, while it has high level methods, framework wise, it's very low level (which is why I call it a toolkit rather then a framework). jQuery UI is a higher level framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what you need to do.

If you just want to add some other functionality to jQuery which is not in the jQuery core, such as a gallery, try googling something like:

```
jquery photo gallery
```

However, if you need to develop a fully fledged UI for a very complex web application, you should take a look at [Sensha (aka ExtJS)](http://www.sencha.com/products/js/) which is targeted for such applications.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of popular frameworks, I would say [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) which is built on top of jQuery.

> jQuery UI provides abstractions for low-level interaction and animation,
> advanced effects and high-level, themeable widgets, built on top of the
> jQuery JavaScript Library, that you can use to build highly interactive
> web applications.

The features in jQueryUI 1.8.6 at the time of writing include:

> Complex behaviors like drag and drop, resizing, selection and sorting.
>
> Configurable and themeable widgets such as Accordian, Autocomplete, Button, Datepicker, Dialog, Progressbar, Slider and Tabs
>
> Various utilities and effects

There are of course many popular standalone [jQuery plugins](http://plugins.jquery.com/) as well.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most popular javascript framework in combination with jQuery?

jQuery plugin framework.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the most popular additional library to jquery?

jQuery is getting a bit long in the tooth. While it is great for simple tasks, if you are looking for a larger feature set, it is highly encouraged to use a modern framework like React or Vue.js.

My colleague wrote a great article to start your learning with Vue.js. Give it a read if you are interested in learning more: [Will Vue Become the Most Popular Front-end Framework in 2023?](https://www.scalablepath.com/front-end/vue-js-popularity-framework#the-future-of-vue)